# jQuery height() function requires different arguments depending on the browser

Tags: jquery, html

I have an html site with a table on it and I try to generate an exact copy of the table with jQuery. height() function returns different values for different browsers (it seems that Mozilla and Opera take top border width into consideration, while Chrome and Explorer does not). 
For example:
in Mozilla: height(): 38, innerHeight(): 41, outerHeight: 42
in Chrome: height(): 37, innerHeight(): 40, outerHeight: 42

The real problem, however, occurs while setting the cell height in 'table copy'.

```
$clCol.find("td").each(function(index) {
    if ($.browser.mozilla || $.browser.opera) {
        $(this).height(tds[index].outerHeight());
    } else {
        $(this).height(tds[index].height());
    }
});
```

It seems that height() function require different values in different browsers to display the same thing!
Is there any general way to do this without IF on browser type?
Any jQuery function(s) to obtain what exactly is needed as height() argument?

Answer (score 0):

if you read this 
http://api.jquery.com/height/

Then it would explain why that happens :)

further more you may try to use the `.css({'height'})` method to get the value of height.

one more thing, in ie6 at least is a well known problem where the margin are twice as much when the width is used as well as margin.